# Mapbox - extruding lines

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

Is it possible to apply fill-extrusion for a GeoJSON LineString feature?
Basically I'm looking for a way to draw lines (can be 1 line or multiple connected) in a 3d mode with z-offset.

If that's not possible, maybe this can be done with a polygon instead?
Like, converting my lines to polygons (how can i do that?)

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking for isn't yet implemented, but ticketed in Mapbox GL JS at https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/3993.

For now you'll need to opt for your second suggestion of converting the LineString feature to a Polygon. You can do this with turf's buffer function http://turfjs.org/docs#buffer.

The whole line/polygon will be offset at the same height, so depending on your application you could use turf's linkChunk http://turfjs.org/docs#lineChunk to get it broken up into smaller features which you assign different height properties to.

Comment: Is there any update on that ? or still the same workaround ? could not find anything. thanks