# Mapbox 3D line workaround

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I have a map from mapbox that has multiple markers as coordinates and one line that joins them together, I've experimented with the 3D feature and realised that at the moment lines cannot be extruded although polygons can.

So I was wondering if it is possible to convert my line into multiple different polygons to be able to extrude it at different heights, either that or set each marker as its own height then create a line/polygon that joins them together?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47283304/mapbox-extruding-lines

Comment: @AndrewHarvey that doesnt really help me. I've tried that but I cant seem to get different heights to work

Comment: I'm not sure which part you're stuck with. You just need to use turf.linkChunk to break your line into smaller segments, each with it's own height attribute, then convert the line segments to polygons with turf.buffer. Then it's just https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/3d-buildings/

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for isn't yet implemented, but ticketed in Mapbox GL JS at https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/3993.

For now you'll need to opt for converting the LineString feature to a Polygon. You can do this with turf's buffer function http://turfjs.org/docs#buffer.

The whole line/polygon will be offset at the same height, so depending on your application you could use turf's linkChunk http://turfjs.org/docs#lineChunk to get it broken up into smaller features which you assign different height properties to.

Comment: Is there any way to split the line at specific markers rather than a set interval?